# Determining if Gulp task called from another task

Tags: gulp

Is there a way to find out if a task been invoked directly or from another task?

```
  runSequence = require 'run-sequence'

  gulp.task 'build', ->
     ....

  gulp.task 'run', ->
     runSequence 'build', -> gulp.start('server')
```

I need an `if` case in `build` task that says: 
if it was called directly - (`gulp build`) then do something;

or if it was invoked from `run` task then do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/205486). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

**But to answer the question**; I think the only way is to look at the call stack trace and make sure only Gulp touches the task. I wrote a function that finds who orchestrated the task. You can just put the function inline with your `gulpfile.js` and use it like boolean.

The following code relies on [`npm parse-stack`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/parse-stack) so make sure to `npm install parse-stack`

Usage: `if(wasGulpTaskCalledDirectly()) { /*...*/ }`

```
function wasGulpTaskCalledDirectly()
{
    var parseStack = require("parse-stack");

    var stack = parseStack(new Error());

    // Find the index in the call stack where the task was started
    var stackTaskStartIndex = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++)
    {
        if(stack[i].name == 'Gulp.Orchestrator.start')
        {
            stackTaskStartIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Once we find where the orchestrator started the task
    // Find who called the orchestrator (one level up)
    var taskStarterIndex = stackTaskStartIndex+1;
    var isValidIndex = taskStarterIndex > 0 && taskStarterIndex < stack.length;
    if(isValidIndex && /gulp\.js$/.test((stack[taskStarterIndex].filepath || "")))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

You can find my full `gulpfile.js` used for testing below:

```js
// This is a test for this SE question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25928170/796832
// Figure out how to detect `gulp` vs `gulp build`

// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');


// Add this in from the above code block in the answer
//function wasGulpTaskCalledDirectly()
 // ...

gulp.task('build', function() {
 //console.log(wasGulpTaskCalledDirectly());
 if(wasGulpTaskCalledDirectly())
 {
  // Do stuff here
 }
 else
 {
  // Do other stuff here
 }

 return gulp.src('./index.html', {base: './'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

// This does nothing
gulp.task('start-server', function() {
 return gulp.src('./index.html', {base: './'});
});


// Default Task
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
 runSequence('build',
  ['start-server'],
  callback
 );
});
```

Comment: wow... that is amazing... I have no idea what does this thing do, yet I feel it's awesome...

Comment: errmm... What am I trying to accomplish? I dunno... I do sometimes complicate my own life. I had no idea that this is not an easy problem. Still I'm curious